# Adding field in table counting from different table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv

I just started to work with QGIS recently and am struggling with the following:

- I have <kbd>**1**</kbd> a CSV table on offshore branches of certain institutions including info on their respective countries of origin. No geographical data except the columns with country names (`Home Country`, `Host Country`).

  Here is an example of the table with the relevant columns:

| Institution name | Institution Branch | Home Country | Host Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | xxx2 | Germany | Saudi Arabia |
| yyy | yyy2 | Germany | India |
| zzz | zzz2 | USA | India |

- I also have <kbd>**2**</kbd> a polygon layer with the world countries in which each country takes 1 row, and each with it's own polygon represented in the shapefile (the country name column is named `name`)

Both attribute tables use the same format for the country names.

Now I would like to

1. add a field (column) to the <kbd>**2**</kbd> country layer's attribute table that counts for each country how many institutions have it as a `Home Country` in the CSV table. Using the above table as an example, the new column would count 2 for Germany, and 1 for USA.
2. add additional columns to the <kbd>**2**</kbd> country layer's attribute table that count for each country how many institutions have it as a `Home Country` in the CSV table **AND** have a branch in a certain `Host Country`. For example in the above table I would like to only count for those countries with institutions with a branch in `Host Country` = India. The resulting column should count 1 for Germany, and 1 for USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One step for me :

- Select the country layer <kbd>**2**</kbd>, open field calculator, name your new field of type `Integer` and compute it with the expression :

```
coalesce(
  aggregate(
    layer:= 'offshore_institutions_layer_name',
    aggregate:= 'sum',
    expression:= 1,
    filter:= "Home Country" = attribute(@parent, 'name')
  )
  , 0)
```

**Explanation** :

This expression aggregate the <kbd>**1**</kbd> offshore institutions with the same `"Home Country"` name as the current country layer <kbd>**2**</kbd> feature `"Home Country"` value, and `sum` the value **1** for each (it's the same as `count` in this case).

For the second part, you can add a condition to your filter :

```
filter:= "Home Country" = attribute(@parent, 'name') AND "Host Country" = 'India'
```